# ¿Cómo puedo establecer la posición de una lista desplegable con D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dropdownlist, d3-v4.js

Quiero establecer la posicion de un lista desplegable con D3.js pero a diferencia de otros elementos, el elemento  no tiene los atributos x e y por lo que no se como hacerlo.

```
d3.select("#chart")
             .append("select")
             .attr("id","desplegable")
             .on('change',onchange)
             .selectAll("option")
             .data(preguntas)
             .enter()
             .append("option")
             .attr("value", function(d){return d;})
             .text(function(d){return d;})
          ;
```

Ademas, he intentado insertar la lista desplegable dentro de un svg pero no ha funcionado.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
            .attr("id","svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 


   svg.append("select")
             .attr("id","desplegable")
             .on('change',onchange)
             .selectAll("option")
             .data(preguntas)
             .enter()
             .append("option")
             .attr("value", function(d){return d;})
             .text(function(d){return d;})
      ;
```

Comment: Hola Edu, bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero completar el [tour] para que te familiarices con el funcionamiento del lugar y de paso ganar tu primera medalla.